# Can I send a different passport than I applied for the Canadian visa with?

Tags: visas, passports, canada

I have applied for a Canada Visitor visa and after a long long wait, I have received a letter from Canada requesting I send my passport to the embassy. My passport will expire after exactly one year and as I know they will not issue a visa beyond the expiry date on the passport.

When I applied I provided my current passport details. Can I apply for a new passport and send the new passport to the embassy? Or do I have to provide the same passport that I detailed when I applied for the visa?

Comment: You probably have to submit the same passport. Call embassy and confirm if you can change the passport.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about Canada, but in the UK, any visas issued will not expire with the passport. The traveller is quite able to renew their passport, but present both passports when entering the country.

The current (new) passport will establish nationality and identity, and the old (expired) passport will contain the still-valid visa.

So providing Canada's system works in a similar manner, you should just ask for the visa to be issued in your current passport - but then when it expires and you get a new one, make sure you keep the old one with the visa.

Source: I'm a former UK Immigration Officer, and I saw this all the time.

Comment: While Canada does still consider unexpired visas in expired passports as valid, from a decade ago or so, the department policy has been that immigration officers are supposed to issue visas with a validity period that coincides with the passport except under particular circumstances.

Comment: @xngtng that sounds like it would make an answer to the original question

Comment: The reason the OP wants to renew their passport is so that they can get a 10 year validity visa instead of 1 year. Canada normally issues visitor visa valid till the expiry of the passport, upto a maximum of 10 years.